# .htaccess rewriterule not working correct on mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website project on my mac book pro leopard, and I am using built in apache2 and php. I've made my configurations in both httpd.conf and user.conf to use htaccess. Changes done like :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory >
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The problem is when i want to open a site like 
localhost/~username/site/site/index.php/welcome, index.php does some operations and finds the right controller and the right page.

But when I try to enter site like site/welcome apache gives me the following error :

Not Found

The requested URL Users/username/Sites/site/index.php/welcome was not found on this server.

The problem is apache gets this like it is indeed a file and the error statement gives it in a file system way, but this request must be fetched to index.php instead.

my .htaccess file looks like this

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

What bothers me that this configuration works on both Linux and Windows but does not work on Mac. I feel doomed : )

Comment: Can you confirm the rewrite module has been enabled correctly?

Comment: yes i can see them in the loaded modules section of phpinfo();

Comment: Would you consider changing your accepted answer? The one you have accepted is actually incorrect. The answer by @tong is correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I met the same problem too! 'DocumentRoot' doesn't work for me in Lion.

But this works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /~username/YOURPath

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Fantastic! I spent like three hours trying to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: i faced the same problem but its save my time so +1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is correct - RewriteBase should always be set. Modifying DocumentRoot is a hack (and wouldn't be possible from .htaccess on a well configured server).

Comment: I have the same problem but RewriteBase did not work
AH00526: Syntax error on line 8 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:
RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OSX Mountain Lion, make sure `AllowOverride` is set to `All` on Directory /

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

and root directory of your document root path:

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

also make sure that `FollowSymLinks` is included in `Options`.

if your "index.php-less pretty URL" is not on your DocumentRoot then add the following RewriteBase directory on your .htaccess file where your index.php exists, like the following example:

```
RewriteBase /~username/site/site/
```

If you would like to change the `.htaccess` file name to something else like `.acl` or `htaccess.txt`, uncomment the following line on your httpd.conf

```
# Various default settings
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf
```

and change `.htaccess` in `AccessFileName` directive to anything you like in `extra/httpd-default.conf` file. For example if you would like to change `.htaccess` file to `htaccess.txt` change it to:

```
AccessFileName htaccess.txt
```

save them, restart your apache web server on OSX Mountain Lion, and hope you are good to go.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
DocumentRoot "/~username/site/"
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem but the solutions above did not work for me,

Removing the slash from the beginning did the trick (i guess because my browser already runs under the correct user).

So RewriteRule ^Register /register.php

Became RewriteRule ^Register register.php

That drove me nuts! BTW I am running xampp (apache 2) on mac os 10.8 .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but for me the problem was that `mod_rewrite` was not enabled.

I had to uncomment these two line in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php7_module        libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

After that there was no need to use `RewriteBase` etc.

Comment: exactly, i totally forgot to enable the module. nice

Answer (score 0):

If I place a .htaccess into /Library/WebServer/Documents and open "localhost/"; to test it, this works as expected. It just doesn't work in "~/Sites".