# Remove index.php codeIgniter in xampp mac os 10.9 not work

Tags: macos, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, xampp

I already develop a system in windows base machine using xampp and codeIgnitor, So i change development environment to mac os 10.9 same system give me error 404. So putting index.php to the URL the issue fixed. But I wonder how it's happen. Cause I already remove index.php using htaccess file in windows environment. I want to know how I remove index.php in mac os 10.9.

**This is my htaccess file content.**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf
File also edited as follows**

- enable rewrite module "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"
- change username

  User ******
  Group daemon
- change permissions

  AllowOverride All
      Require all granted

**CodeIgnitor config file also edited as follows**

```
- change base url

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci2.2/';

 - Remove index.php

    $config['index_page'] = '';

 - Change URL Protocol

    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**I put my files in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ci2.2 directory**

Answer (score 0):

Try this htacess content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Reference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

If you are using a subdirectory, replace the last line by this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /[SUBDIRECTORY]/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Replace [SUBDIRECTORY] by your the directory name

Comment: Thanks Amir for quick response. I try it also. But not work. I assume the problem is htaceess not working in Mac os 10.9. Please guide me. Thanks again.

Comment: @nithin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941958/htaccess-rewriterule-not-working-correct-on-mac

Comment: in that example localhost/~username/site/site/index.php/welcome and in my case localhost/ci2.2/index.php/welcome. So they say it work when used RewriteBase /~username/YOURPath . So I used RewriteBase /ci2.2 . But it not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case following code works fine

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /projects/hc/homecare/trunk/homecare 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/hc/homecare/trunk/homecare/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

ref : [link](http://%20RewriteEngine%20On%20%20%20%20%20%20RewriteBase%20/projects/hc/homecare/trunk/homecare%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RewriteCond%20%25%7BREQUEST_FILENAME%7D%20!-f%20%20%20%20%20%20RewriteCond%20%25%7BREQUEST_FILENAME%7D%20!-d%20%20%20%20%20%20RewriteCond%20$1%20!%5E(index%5C.php%7Cimages%7Crobots%5C.txt%7Ccss%7Cdocs%7Cjs%7Csystem)%20%20%20%20%20%20RewriteRule%20%5E(.*)$%20/projects/hc/homecare/trunk/homecare/index.php?/$1%20%5BL%5D)